# Error message : SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks, fetch-api

i was trying to fetch a data for a project but everytime i'm converting the fetch data to json it returns me

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

i don't understand why it's showing me this

```
import React,{useContext,useState,useEffect} from 'react'

const url = 'www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s='


export default function AppProvider({children}) {
    const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [searchTerm,setSearchTerm] = useState('a') 
//set it as 'a' for suggestion at search bar at beginning.
    const [cocktails,setCocktails] = useState([])

    const fetchUrl = async ()=>{
        setLoading(true)
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`${url}${searchTerm}`)
//(${url}${searchterm} helps me to fetch data at first with names that starts with 'a' for suggestion///
            const data = await response.json()
            setLoading(false)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchUrl()
    },[searchTerm])
```

please visit the API page from the URL & see if there's an issue with the data. the data is not fetching. what's the issue?

[Link](https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=a)

Comment: ```async function dataJSON() {
  const response = await fetch('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=a');
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
}
dataJSON()();``` I have run this code just by replacing you api and it's loading data as it suppose to

Comment: what am i doing wrong then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing

```
fetch('www.thecocktaildb.com/')
```

will fetch not *that* website, but that path *relative to the current path*. For example, doing so here on Stack Overflow results in the URL being fetched being

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72914244/www.thecocktaildb.com/
```

which, of course, doesn't exist - and presumably that URL doesn't exist on your site either.

Use the full path.

```
const url = 'https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s='
```

I'd also recommend only calling the API when `searchTerm` isn't empty, and perhaps add a debounce of a few hundred milliseconds so as not to call it too often and to keep the client from being blocked.

Comment: i'm using the full path url that you gave me.  const url = 'https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s='

Comment: is that url working for you?

Comment: You are not using the full path - you're missing the leading `https://`. Copy my code exactly. Yes, that URL is working for me.

Comment: yes! Now it works! damn, can't believe i was breaking my keyboard for this silly little mistake!!! is it a must to add that https in every link for fetching??

Comment: Add it when fetching an external URL, or when using any URL not relative to the current page.